# not able get message in chat application when successfully logs in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a simple chat application.. I have used the below link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17617/Create-a-Chat-System-using-Ajax-and-ASP-NET

After writing below code  able to redirect to chat.aspx page

```
       protected void btnJoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (getUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                if(c.CheckUser(txtUserName.Text))
                {
                   // lblError.Text = "You are in the chat room already!";
 Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
                    Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">" + "\n");
                    Response.Write("window.open(\"Chat.aspx\",\"chat\",\"width=800\",\"height=600\",\"toolbar=no\",\"menubar=no\")" + "\n</script>");
                }
                else
                {
                    c.AddCustomer(txtUserName.Text);
                    cc.joinRoom(txtUserName.Text);
                    Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
                    Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">" + "\n");
                    Response.Write("window.open(\"Chat.aspx\",\"chat\",\"width=800\",\"height=600\",\"toolbar=no\",\"menubar=no\")" + "\n</script>");
                    //Response.Redirect("Chat.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Login Failed";
            }
        }
```

But i can see the name of user repeatedly in a right panel...I f two user are online the only the name of two user should display but i can see the name of same user more than once

Comment: Ok you need to give more information here. What have you tried? How do you plan to do this? Are you asking for a way to do this?

Comment: well, I don't think you'll find a link for doing this, your question is not specific enough, but you can start by storing your user's files and keep the path of these files in your database, then you can add rights (in your database) so that the users can specify who can see their files, that's a way to do this. If you have a more specific problem about this you should edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made changes in CustomerManagement.cs and now its working

```
 public void AddCustomer(string sUser)
        {
            string cAddText = "<STRONG>" + sUser + "</STRONG>";
            if (CheckUser(sUser)==false)
            {
                cArray.Add(cAddText);
            }

            if (cArray.Count > 200)
            {
                cArray.RemoveRange(0, 10);
            }
        }
```